# Browser tab close event in angular 6 only works in debug mode

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to capture browser events like tab-close and refresh in my angular 6 Application. It's working fine in debug mode but its not working if I close debug mode and run the application. below is the piece of code

```
registerDOMEvents() {
  window.addEventListener('unload', () => {
    if (this.validNavigation === 0) {
      this.endSession();
    }
  });
  document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    const key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key === 116) {
      this.validNavigation = 1;
    }
  });
}
endSession() {
  this.logout();
  localStorage.clear();
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.registerDOMEvents();
}
```

What might me the problem for this issue?

Comment: have you use @HostLisener instead of directly using addEventListener

Comment: Yeah at first I used @HostListner only.. but I was facing same issue in that also.

Comment: @BearNithi I think before calling the event , the tab close is happening..so that without debug mode its not working.. Do I need to change any configuration or something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `beforeunload` instead of `unload`. `beforeunload` is more reliable and triggers when the document and its resources are about to be unloaded whereas `unload` fires when page is already unloading.

Your `endSession()` must be synchronous, since browser will not wait when any callbacks will be called. As I know angular http service doesn't provide synchronous http calls, but you can do it by yourself with `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open("POST", "http://url/to/endsession", false); // third parameter indicates sync xhr
  client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  client.send('{userId: "42"}');
  console.log('done!!!'); // outputs when a response is received 
});
```

Also take a look this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon). Probably you can use `navigator.sendBeacon` if a browser of your clients supports that feature.

Comment: That's superb answer.

Comment: @AlbertK Yeah.. the thing is beforeunload is triggering for both refresh and tab close .. is there any way to differentiate it ?

Comment: Browsers don't provide such API, so it is a big challenge. You need to handle  `keydown` event like you do, hyperlinks click event, `Refresh` button click (as I know it is impossible) and etc.

Comment: @AlbertK Even though I am using beforeunload, facing same problem its working in debug mode but without debug mode its not working..

Comment: @AlbertK I need to make an API call to back-end as soon as user closes browser tab.. Here the problem is its not waiting for back-end response.. so that without debug mode its not making API call only

Comment: how do you make the request? is it synchronous?

Comment: @AlbertK Yeah I have tried using async/await also..but didn't help

Comment: you should use only synchronous. Async/await is asynchronous and it definitely will not work.

Comment: @AlbertK Okiee.. If u have any example plz provide me the link.. It would help me to solve the problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
@HostListener('window:unload')
async ngOnDestroy() {

  await this.oneService.handleSignOut();

}
```

This will only hit at the time of close window/Tab.