# How can i call an API when my application is going to close

Tags: angular, angular-http

I want to hit an API to set the last active time of the user.
But the API is not hitting.
As time is taken by the API to initialize and hit the server and before the API hit starts, the application got closed

I tried this code in my app.component.ts file

```js
    @HostListener('window:beforeunload', [ '$event' ])
      beforeUnloadHander(event) {
        this._apiService.setLastActive({time:new Date().getTime()/1000})
          .subscribe(data => {
          },err=> {
          })
      }
```

Can anybody suggest when can I call the API to set the last active status of the user?

Comment: Try this: beforeUnloadHander(event) {
    this._apiService.setLastActive({time:new Date().getTime()/1000})
      .subscribe(data => {
return true
      },err=> {
      }); 
 return false;
  }

more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229942/how-to-block-users-from-closing-a-window-in-javascript

Comment: It prompts the user to leave the site. is there some other way without prompting the user. And it didn't work when I closed the browser

Comment: You might want to look into some solution using polling, because relying on code to run before closing can cause problems. What if the browser/computer shuts down unexpectedly?

Answer (score 1):

Please use  `ngOnDestroy()` Inside the component.ts file of the exiting component.

**Features**
It clean up just before Angular destroys the directive/component. Unsubscribe Observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks and called just before Angular destroys the directive/component.https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

If you have unsaved changes. try this stackoverflow answer
[Confirmation before closing of tab/browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54920520/982517. Seems like beforeunload doesn't support async, so you will have to use XMLHttpRequest to call your API.

From the other post:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (event) {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open("POST", "http://url/to/endsession", false); // third parameter indicates sync xhr
  client.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  client.send('{userId: "42"}');
  console.log('done!!!'); // outputs when a response is received 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript code, May be it will work for you.

```
window.onbeforeunload = e => {
    e.returnValue = 'Do you really want to leave this site?';
    return dialogText;
};
```